# Text selection tooltip with Popper.js not positioning successfuly

Tags: javascript, css, popper.js

I'm trying to use [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) to show a tooltip for a text selection.
I'm passing a virtual element to the popper constructor, which contains the selection range bounding rectangle.

The tooltip seems to have it's transform property updated successfully, but it doesn't affect the element, which always stays on the top left.

**With text selected, that's the tooltip CSS properties:**

```
position: absolute;
inset: 0px auto auto 0px;
margin: 0px;
transform: translate(225.833px, 65.8333px);
```

**And that's the result:**

[image: Tooltip stays on the top left]

Why is that happening?

You can see the live code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/popper-text-selection-tooltip-70457).

Comment: Can't seem to get you code working. `Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index.`

Comment: The css animation of Popper.js is overriding your transform. It may be better to make your own tooltip as Popper.js may not be suitable for you.

Comment: Thanks @Naseki! That animation is not Popper's animation, but a custom animation I applied to the tooltip, which indeed overrode Popper's transform property.